# Setting image src in xsl-fo

Tags: xml, xslt, pdf

I have xml files that will supply the name of a file for an image.

```
 <task>
      <header>Diagram</header>
      <image>image.png</image> 
 </task>
```

In the xls-fo I am trying to use:

```
 <xsl:template match="image">
    <fo:block>
        <fo:external-graphic>
            <xsl:attribute name="src">./<xsl:value-of select="image"/></xsl:attribute>
        </fo:external-graphic>
    </fo:block>
 </xsl:template>
```

This does not create an error but the image does not appear in the pdf. In order to get the image to appear I have to hard code the name of the file like this:

```
 <xsl:attribute name="src">./image.png<xsl:value-of select="image"/></xsl:attribute>
```

How do I get the name of the file from the xml to work with the path provided in the xsl.

Comment: Use `<xsl:value-of select="."/>`. Your template already is in the context of `image`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You template is *already matching `image`*. Inside it you are in the *context* of that element, which has no `image` *child*, but just the *text node* you want to select. When you use `<xsl:value-of select="image"/>` inside it, you are actually trying something like `task/image/image`.

Replace `image` in your `value-of` with `.` (the string value of the node) or `text()` (its text contents). Any option will have the same result.

```
<xsl:template match="image">
    <fo:block>
        <fo:external-graphic>
            <xsl:attribute name="src">./<xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:attribute>
        </fo:external-graphic>
    </fo:block>
 </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks. I thought I had tried that and either did not or missed the result as being what I wanted.  That's what happens when you are trying to many options at once.